# How to trim table cell values in MS Word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, iteration, cell, trim

I have a table in a Word file.
This vba program below will iterate through all the table cells

```
Dim strCellText As String
Dim uResp As String
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

Dim itable As Table


For Each itable In ThisDocument.Tables

    uResp = ""

    For Row = 1 To itable.Rows.Count

        For Col = 1 To itable.Columns.Count

            strCellText = itable.Cell(Row, Col).Range.Text
            uResp = uResp & Trim(strCellText)                

        Next

    Next

    MsgBox uResp
Next
```

In the line `uResp = uResp & Trim(strCellText)`   VBA appends a newline and a dot to each cell.So `MsgBox uResp` will display a 'column' message box.How can I remove the newline and dot while displaying the message box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Word uses two characters as the cell delimiter, so use

```
uResp = uResp & Trim(left(strCellText,len(StrCellText)-2))
```

In this case, you will have no separator between the cell values, so you might want to concatenate a space.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264409%28v=office.14%29.aspx) function and [InstrRev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251545%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to find the last newline and . in the celltext, then [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251556%28v=office.14%29.aspx) the celltext and store the Cleaned result

```
strCellText = itable.Cell(Row, Col).Range.Text
'added
Clean = Trim(strcelltext)
posFromEnd = InStrRev(Clean, vbCr + chr(7)) 'obviously a newline and a chr(7) ..
If (posFromEnd > 0) Then
    Clean = Trim(Left(Clean, posFromEnd - 1))
End If
'end added
uResp = uResp & Clean  'updated
```

To verify what the last chars are in the string do this in the debugger:

```
strCellText = itable.Cell(Row, Col).Range.Text
For r = 1 To Len(strCellText)
  c = Mid(strCellText, r, 1)
  Debug.Print Right("0" + Hex(Asc(c)), 2) + " ";
Next
Debug.Print 'set a breakpoint here
```

From the immediate window copy the result so we can reason from there

Comment: Introduction of Clean is giving no effect.@rene, Can you do it in a simple word table and verify?

Comment: I think you simply need to take off the last two characters which Word uses to move to the next table cell, but don't you then want to put some separator between each cell ?

Comment: @grahamj42. I want to select the table cell values as strings only. I dont want any seperator between the cells.

Comment: Verified and fixed, a newline (vbCR) and a Chr(7) are added by Word in a tablecell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure this will ALWAYS happen you could just shorten the string by two characters:

```
 MsgBox LEFT(uResp,LEN(uResp)-2)
```

EDIT:
    Of course, vinod is correct. Not uResp has to be shortend, but strCellText. But this answer has already been given. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: You program removes last two table cells from the end result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is:

```
endOfCell = Chr(13) + Chr(7)
uResp = uResp & Split(strCellText, endOfCell)(0)
```