# If TABLE CELL VALUE = .... THEN (not working)

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word

I have the following code that looks in a document for a sentence with 'pm' in - if found it replaces it with the value is a master document table 2 cells 2,2.

For some reason the IF statement is not working and always goes to the ELSE IF not replacing the text in the document - can any one help me with this as I've been stuck all morning.

```
timeon = wdDocSrc.Tables(2).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text
If timeon = "a" Then  'ERROR HERE
TimeReplace = wdDocSrc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 1)

TimeText = TimeReplace

wdDocTgt.Activate

With wdDocTgt
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="pm", Forward:=True

If Selection.Text = "pm" Then
With Selection
 ' Collapse current selection to insertion point.
.Collapse
 ' Turn extend mode on.
.Extend
 ' Extend selection to word.
.Extend
 ' Extend selection to sentence.
.Extend
 End With
 With Selection
    'Selection.Text = "We are now open Christmas DAY!!. "
    Selection.Text = TimeText

End With

Else
MsgBox "No timing in this letter"
End If
End With
Else
MsgBox "ERROR" 'AWAYS JUMPS TO THIS
End If
```

Comment: Can you not check what `timeon` contains an that point?

Comment: Timeon contains the value in the cell specified (when checking the immediate window). There is a black circle next to it - does that affect it and if so how do i remove it from the table?

Comment: This is a line break followed by the table cell terminator character. You might want to remove them before comparing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim table cell values in MS Word with VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585202/how-to-trim-table-cell-values-in-ms-word-with-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the black did did work - using this code:

```
timeon = wdDocSrc.Tables(3).Cell(2, 2)
Timeconfig = timeon
Timeconfig = Left$(Timeconfig, Len(Timeconfig) - 2)
If Timeconfig = "Yes" Then
TimeReplace = wdDocSrc.Tables(2).Cell(2, 1)

TimeText = TimeReplace
```